# How can I alphabetize Python functions using Sublime Text?

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3

I installed a plugin that will alphabetize blocks. I just need a way to select all the defs in a python file. So far I've got this regex.

[image: Selects all defs except the last line.]

This doesn't select the last line because there isn't any newline. I could enter a newline at the end, but I'd like to avoid that. In fact, ideally I'd like to avoid grabbing all the newlines above.

[image: Selects all defs without any unnecessary newlines]

But I'm worried that if I don't grab the newline, then it won't match functions that have a blank line in the middle.

[image]

If there's a better way than what I'm trying--by selecting the blocks and using an alphabetizer plugin--then please suggest it. Otherwise, is there some way I can get the regex to match just the defs?

Comment: i'm using the sublime-alphabetizer package after selecting the functions

Comment: Does your file only contain `def` blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def.+(\n?\n.+)+`

Will accomplish what you want. (Sublime seems to follow the usual "dot is not newline" convention)

---

Breaking down the components of the expression:

`def.+` - match the def line, up to a newline

`\n?\n.+` - match a newline, followed by some characters, optionally prepended by another newline (the prepend handles the case of an empty line in the middle of a def)

`(...)+` - start a capture group, and match its pattern one or more times

`(\n?\n.+)+` - combine the previous two pieces, so we match any sequence of non-empty lines with at most one empty line between any two non-empty lines (pedantically, any sequence of non-empty-line and empty-line-then-non-empty-line blocks)

The final `+` could be a `*` instead if it's permissable to match "empty" defs like

```
def empty():
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(\s*)(def.*(?:\n\1\s+.*|\n\s*)+$)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20980563)

Comment: @stovfl what criticism? can you read? sincerely, get help, soon.

Comment: @stovfl so before I answer I should edit the question even though I did understood it clearly

Comment: Sorry my bad. Should read: You can edit the answer to improve the clarity and focus - this can reduce the chances of the answer being closed or deleted. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)